# Add line break to HTML after text addition

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am adding text to an existing string in HTML.

```
added = soup.find(text=re.compile('Summary|Experience'))
added.insert(0, NavigableString(code))
```

I would like to also add a line break after the text inserted so each string is on a different line.

I tried:

```
added.insert(0, NavigableString(code)+'<br/>')
```

And some other variations too...

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.new_tag`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) method to create your `<br>` tag

*Demo*

```
In [22]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [23]: soup = BeautifulSoup("""<p>Experience</p><strong>Summary</strong>""")

In [24]: newtg = soup.new_tag('br')

In [25]: soup.insert(0, newtg)

In [26]: soup
Out[26]: <br/><html><body><p>Experience</p><strong>Summary</strong></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This definitely adds the line before Experience/Summary. Since I am also adding the string (code) before Experience and on the same line, I would like the space to be added after (code) and before Experience. I tried changing the index but did not work...

Comment: @Diego you can use [insert_before or insert_after](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) to insert element before or after something

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, How should I instrument it? I am getting error messages...Thanks!

Comment: `NotImplementedError: BeautifulSoup objects don't support insert_before()`

Comment: @Diego please take a look at the [doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) it is well explained

Comment: finally made it work! Thanks for the patience, the follow up and the education. Best.